# How to activate Woocommerce Filter Scripts in Homepage

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, hook-woocommerce

I would like to use the price filter and the attribute filter in homepage but I have seen that scripts are disabled.
For example I tried to paste the code of the widget woocommerce widget_price_filter into the homepage code, the graphic is visible but the functionality is not active (the filter cursor does not move).
I'm not a php expert and I ask if anyone can suggest me how to do a function to activate the scripts that I need in homepage. 
Thank's in advance.

Comment: Is there any error showing while you are add code of widget  wocommerce in the home page? @Ro Li

Comment: No nothing. I put the filter price in the sidebar of the store page and it obviously works. Then I copied the html to the home page, see the filter price graphic but the cursors do not move. There are no script errors in 'console'.

Comment: might be chance of any plugin conflict. please check after deactivate another plugins.

Comment: I checked the page source of shop and home. There's not the jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3 script. URL..js/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery-ui-touch-punch.min.js?ver=3.7.0'> in the homepage. I'm tryng a functions but it doesn't work. `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_script', 11 ); function custom_wp_enqueue_script() { if ( is_page('home') ) { wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-touch-punch' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'price-slider' ); } }`